# How can I extend my loading page's timer to 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a loader for my website, but the problem I have right now is that the loader ends in like 0.1 second because my site load to quick to see the loader.

So my question: How can I extend to show the loader before it goes to my site?
I want to do a loading animation of like 2-3 seconds and then go to my website.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
    document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can add a timeout before stopping the loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` function of javascript below is code

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
  document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
},3000)
```

Above code should be load event of window

Answer (score 3):

Put your code inside a `setTimeout` Callback.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Your code here...
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can add the DOMContentLoaded to ensure the page was finished to load and add a setTimeout with your timer delay.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let overlay = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0];
  let loading = document.getElementsByClassName("loading")[0];

  setTimeout(() => {
    loading.remove();
    overlay.classList.add("loaded");
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;
}

.overlay.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  The page content.
</div>
<div class="loading">
  Page is loading
</div>
```